# MySQL group by only on specific amount of records (query inside JOIN expression)

Tags: mysql

I have a History table that represents messages that are stored by some sort of chat program.

It has a user id, message & datetime. (specified on: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49fcefb/5)

Now, what I want is to have a result which contains:

- The max amount of messages typed by date
- What user has the most messages and howmany messages this user typed)

I got it working, but I find the query rather slow, I think its because of the last GROUP BY (GROUP BY b.cnt) as this will group over all the records found.

Query:

```
SELECT b.cnt as dayCount, a.cnt as userCount, a.userid as userId, b.date
 FROM (
        select date_added as date, user_id as userid, count(*) as cnt from history group by userid, day(date_added),month(date_added),year(date_added)
      ) a
 INNER JOIN (
        select date_added as date, count(*) as cnt from history group by day(date_added),month(date_added),year(date_added)
      ) b ON year(a.date) = year(b.date)
          AND month(a.date) = month(b.date)
          AND day(a.date) = day(b.date)
GROUP BY b.cnt
ORDER BY dayCount desc, userCount desc limit 10;
```

Can someone advice me on how to solve this? Maybe with another sort of query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based  on the sample in your sqlfidle .. you should also add  the expected  result  ..

Comment: Are you using indexes ? If yes what are the indexes?

Comment: @scaisEdge: The expected result, is exactly as shown on the fiddle, the query is not fast enough

Comment: @DanIonescu: There is a primary key on history_id & index on user_id

Comment: then your question is only about how improve performance ??? please confirm

Comment: @scaisEdge yes it is

Comment: @Akra if there is a primary key on history_id there can't be duplicate values. In your sqlfiddle all rows have history_id 1

Comment: @DanIonescu how is this relevant to my question? The fiddle is just quickly made to copy/paste, i've edited it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ead84f/1

Comment: @Akra i'm trying to replicate your problem in my test environment, and indexes are an important part of the performance

Comment: @Akra, may i know which version of mysql are you using? 5.x , 8.x?

Comment: I'm using mysql 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `windows function` with `Subquery` to get the same result.

```
select SQ.daycount,SQ.usercount,SQ.user_id, SQ.date1 from (

    select sum(count(Message)) over (partition by date(date_added)) as daycount, --to get max amount of msg by date
           max(count(Message)) over (partition by date(date_added)) as maxuser,  -- to identify user with most msg
           count(Message) as usercount,
           date(date_added) as date1,user_id from history
           group by date1,user_id ) SQ

where SQ.usercount=SQ.maxuser
```

[**Check the Fiddle here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c0bc32fc98bfa1aad9c588fb0db2edf)

Comment: Thank you! I was already looking into partitioning, but you solved it faster :). (0.4s faster than my original query)

Comment: Welcome! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

seems you are joining with wrong criteria.

first table is getting the # of users, 2nd table is getting the #of days per user_id. see [dbfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49fcefb/39/0)

```
SELECT b.cnt as dayCount, a.cnt as userCount, a.userid as userId, b.date
FROM (
         select 
             user_id as userid
           , count(*) as cnt 
         from history 
         group by userid
      ) a
LEFT JOIN (
        select cast(date_added as date) as date
            , count(*) as cnt 
            , user_id as userid
        from history 
        group by cast(date_added as date)  
      ) b ON a.userid = b.userid
ORDER BY dayCount desc, userCount desc limit 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this does not get the correct user_id who posted the most messages + the userCount is a total count of the table , not for that specific date